# How many different ways are there to split a total of $nk$ different items in $k$ sets, each one of exactly $n$ elements?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I can't think of a way to solve that properly. I have $nk$ elements, and they're all one of a kind. I need to separate them into $k$ sets, each set containing $n$ elements. Should I consider the number of subsets and then the order of the elements in each subset?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  how many ways to select the $n$ elements of the first set?  Now that you have selected them, how many ways to select the $n$ elements of the second set?  Keep going until the end.  Unfortunately, you have overcounted because you can pull out the sets in any order.  How many times have you overcounted?  Divide by that and you are home.

Comment: For the first set I have $\binom{nk}{n}$, right? For the second set, do I need to exclude the first $n$ elements? So $\binom{nk - n}{n}$? I'm trying to develop that idea but it seems to get me nowhere.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.  The first $n$ are gone, so you have $nk-n$ to choose from for the second set.  How many are left to choose from for the third set?  If you express the combination counts as factorials you will find a bunch of cancellation that leaves a pretty pattern.

Comment: So I keep going $\binom{nk}{n}$, $\binom{nk-n}{n}$,...,$\binom{nk-(k-1)n}{n}$, $\binom{nk-kn}{n}$? Should I add them or multiply them? And how can I detect what I'm overcounting?

Comment: You should multiply them, because for each first set you can have that many second sets and so on.  Then reread the last three sentences of the answer.

Comment: I still can't understand what is overcounted here. And for the binomials, the last term should be $$\frac{(nk-kn)!}{n!(nk-(k+1)n)!}$$ and it violates the factorial rule (the number has to be positive).

Comment: Nevermind, I just noticed the last binomial should be $$\binom{nk-(k-1)n}{n} = \binom{n}{n} = 1$$

Comment: So I reached a total of $$\frac{(nk)!}{{(n!)}^{k-1}}$$ and I really don't see anything else to do... Is it the final answer?

Comment: You are off by one in the denominator exponent because ${n \choose n}=\frac {n!}{n!0!}$ and you need that $n!$ in the denominator.  Then we have the overcount.  There are $k$ sets you have selected.  You could have selected any one first, then any other one next, etc. and gotten the same collection of sets.  How many orders give you the same set of sets?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with $n=3$, $k=5$:

```
|*|*|*|*|*|    
|*|*|*|*|*|
|*|*|*|*|*|
```

There are $kn$ elements, which we can arrange in $(kn)!$ ways.
However the $k$ bins are sets, so order will not matter there.

So we end up with
$$
\frac{(kn)!}{(n!)^k}
$$
if I corrected correctly.

However the bins might be not distinguishable, so this might further shrink to
$$
\frac{(kn)!}{(n!)^k \, k!}
$$
I better check this. :-)

So I told my friend Ruby [this](https://gist.github.com/077c3aed6171bd04df369bbe41dfb17c) about the problem.

When asked for the instance $n = 2$, $k = 3$ she replied:

```
sim(2,3)
permutations: 720
predicted: 15
printing up to first 5 inspected permutations..
1:
|1|3|5|
|2|4|6|
[ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ]
2:
|1|3|6|
|2|4|5|
[ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ]
(already found)
3:
|1|3|4|
|2|5|6|
[ [1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 6] ]
4:
|1|3|6|
|2|5|4|
[ [1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 6] ]
(already found)
5:
|1|3|4|
|2|6|5|
[ [1, 2], [3, 6], [4, 5] ]
found: 15
predicted: 15
```

When I asked her about the problem instance $n = 2$, $k = 5$ she replied:

```
sim(2,5)
permutations: 3628800
predicted: 945
printing up to first 5 inspected permutations..
1:
| 1| 3| 5| 7| 9|
| 2| 4| 6| 8|10|
[ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10] ]
2:
| 1| 3| 5| 7|10|
| 2| 4| 6| 8| 9|
[ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10] ]
(already found)
3:
| 1| 3| 5| 7| 8|
| 2| 4| 6| 9|10|
[ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 9], [8, 10] ]
4:
| 1| 3| 5| 7|10|
| 2| 4| 6| 9| 8|
[ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 9], [8, 10] ]
(already found)
5:
| 1| 3| 5| 7| 8|
| 2| 4| 6|10| 9|
[ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9] ]
found: 945
predicted: 945
```

When I asked her about the problem instance $n = 3$, $k = 5$ she replied:

```
sim(3,5)
permutations: 1307674368000
predicted: 1401400
printing up to first 5 inspected permutations..
1:
| 1| 4| 7|10|13|
| 2| 5| 8|11|14|
| 3| 6| 9|12|15|
[ [1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
2:
| 1| 4| 7|10|13|
| 2| 5| 8|11|15|
| 3| 6| 9|12|14|
[ [1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
(already found)
3:
| 1| 4| 7|10|14|
| 2| 5| 8|11|13|
| 3| 6| 9|12|15|
[ [1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
(already found)
4:
| 1| 4| 7|10|14|
| 2| 5| 8|11|15|
| 3| 6| 9|12|13|
[ [1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
(already found)
5:
| 1| 4| 7|10|15|
| 2| 5| 8|11|13|
| 3| 6| 9|12|14|
[ [1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
(already found)
```

Right now she seems to be thinking, I am still waiting for what she found.
Sigh, women. :-)